# How to update already created Outlook Meeting events directly from excel, without duplicating when same field to create meeting is activated again

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I have a sheet, where i allocate staff to specific events and roles for each event. Each staff memeber has an associated letter that i place in a column depending on what role theyre assigned to for each specific event.

When i double click the date column of that event, i have a macro that: Creates an outlook meeting event, takes the name of the event and places it as the subject. The start time from the time column in my sheet along with the date.

It pulls the email addresses associated with each letter in that specific row from the range of cells of position allocation using vlookup.

This all works great.

my question:
If i send an event, it adds to mine and the recipients calendars fine. However, lets say, the name of the event, the time or date or the list of staff allocated to that event changes, i need to re-send the update, however currently it creates a new meeting every time. Is there a way to update the existing one, and sending only an update where necessary to those who had already received the inital meeting and of course a new event for any new recipients it should send to?

Below is my code and a screen shot of my sheet to give you an example:

```
Dim OutApp As Object 
    Dim ObjOutlook As Object 
    Dim ObjMeeting As Object 
    Dim OutMail As Object 
    Dim q As Long 
    Dim c As Long 
    Dim strTo As String 
    Dim strAddress As String 
 
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 
    If Target.Column <> 6 Then Exit Sub 
 
    Cancel = True 
 
    q = Target.Row 
    For c = 11 To 21 
        If Cells(q, c).Value <> "" Then 
            strAddress = Evaluate("IFERROR(VLOOKUP(""" & Cells(q, c).Value & """, AllStaff,2,FALSE),"""")")
            If strAddress <> "" Then 
                strTo = strTo & "; " & strAddress 
            End If 
        End If 
    Next c 
 
    Set ObjOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
    Set ObjMeeting = ObjOutlook.CreateItem(1) 
 
 
    ObjOutlook.Session.Logon 
    ObjMeeting.Display 
    On Error Resume Next 
 
    With ObjMeeting 
        .Meeting = 1 
        If strTo <> "" Then 
            .RequiredAttendees = Mid(strTo, 3) 
        End If 
        .Subject = Range("C" & q) & " - " & Range("E" & q) & " " & Range("F" & q) & " - " & Range("J" & q)
        .Start = Range("F" & q).Value & " " & Format(Range("G" & q).Value, "h:mm") 
        .Duration = 480 
        .ReminderSet = False 
        .BusyStatus = 0 
        .Body =    "This is the actual event start time.  Please arrive in advance at the office.                                          Please accept this meeting but select 'Do not send response' if possible. Unless you need to decline, then let me know with a response. ----- " & Range("C" & q) & " ----- " & Range("E" & q) & " ----- " & Range("F" & q) & " ----- " & "Please, check this schedule for the weekend, if there are any problems or conflicts, contact me ASAP. Thank you!" 
        .Display 
    
End With
```

Tried a few diferent things but my main struggle is finding a way that when i create a meeting, finding a way to link the MeetingID to that specific row that i double clicked to populate the meeting, then finding this whenever i create a meeting from that row again updating only the changes.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the meeting and display it, call `ObjMeeting.Sav`e and read the `ObjMeeting.EntryID` property. You can store the entry id in your Excel spreadsheet. Next time, check if the entry id is already saved and use it to call `ObjOutlook.Session.GetItemFromID` instead of `ObjOutlook.CreateItem(1)` .

Keep in mind that Outlook can recreate an appointment when it receives a meeting update - that will change its entry id and `GetItemFromID` will fail. You'd need to find an appointment with the same appointment id (`AppointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID`), but Outlook does not allow to search for the binary properties in `Items.Find` or `Items.Restrict`, and looping through all items in the Calendar folder is hardly efficient. Redemption (I am its author) allows to search for the binary properties such as `GlobalAppointmentID`. But since you are the organizer, the appointment should stay intact since you are the one who send the meeting updates.

You might also want to update the code

```
Set ObjOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
ObjOutlook.Session.Logon
```

to

```
Set ObjOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
set ns = ObjOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
ns.Logon
```

since `Application.Session` can be null if Outlook is not yet running.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an `AppointmentItem` object from a `MeetingItem` object by using the `GetAssociatedAppointment` method. After that you can add a user property which could identify that appointment item with your Excel entry. The [UserProperties.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties.add) method creates a new user property in the `UserProperties` collection (see the [AppointmentItem.UserProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.userproperties) property).

When required, you may use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class to get an item with a specified user property value. You can read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

Be aware, Outlook is a singleton which means you can't run two instances at the same time on the system. So, your code:

```
Set ObjOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set ObjMeeting = ObjOutlook.CreateItem(1) 

ObjOutlook.Session.Logon
```

which uses the late-binding technology (is there any reason for that?) and calls the `Logon` method does make sense only if you need to use a specific profile. If Outlook is not running and you only want to start Outlook with the default profile, don't use the `Logon` method.

Instead, if you want to make sure that Outlook is initialized correctly, you need to use the following code:

```
Sub InitializeMAPI ()

    ' Start Outlook.
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Get a session object. 
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Create an instance of the Inbox folder. 
    ' If Outlook is not already running, this has the side
    ' effect of initializing MAPI.
    Dim mailFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set mailFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' Continue to use the object model to automate Outlook.
End Sub
```

First, the code instantiates the Outlook `Application` object, then references a default folder such as the `Inbox`. This has the side effect of initializing MAPI to use the default profile and to make the object model fully functional.